# Rails dependent: :destroy causes ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, foreign-key-relationship

I have a User model in my rails app as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :assemblies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :packages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :manufacturers, dependent: :destroy
  //more code here
end
```

I also have `dependent: :restrict` in some other models.

When I run the following in `rails console`, I get an ArgumentError:

```
u = User.first
u.parts
```

The call to `u.parts` gives the following error message:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key: dependent
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:44:in `block in assert_valid_keys'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:43:in `each_key'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:43:in `assert_valid_keys'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:33:in `validate_options'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:24:in `build'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:23:in `build'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:139:in `build'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_and_belongs_to_many.rb:8:in `build'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:13:in `build'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1600:in `has_and_belongs_to_many'
    from /home/david/code/PartSorter/app/models/part.rb:5:in `<class:Part>'
    from /home/david/code/PartSorter/app/models/part.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
... 12 levels...
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:588:in `constantize'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in `block in compute_type'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:109:in `each'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:109:in `compute_type'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:117:in `klass'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:165:in `find_target?'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:332:in `load_target'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:44:in `load_target'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:88:in `method_missing'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working -  I followed the guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to add the `dependent` part but it isn't working. Any ideas?

edit:
the contents of part.rb are as follows:

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :part_packages
  has_many :packages, through: :part_packages
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies, :dependent => :restrict
  belongs_to :user


  validates :name, :user_id, :presence => true

  def quantity
    @quantity = 0
    self.part_packages.each do |pp|
      @quantity += pp.quantity
    end
    @quantity
  end
end
```

Comment: The error is in `app/models/part.rb`, so please provide the code there rather than `user.rb`.

Comment: I have added the source above.

Comment: And what happens when you try `Part.first` and `u.parts.size` from the console? (Narrowing down the area.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:dependent` is not a valid option for [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many), so you need to get rid of it and write your own solution that does what you want.

Alternatively, you may wish to have an explicit join model instead of using `has_and_belongs_to_many`. That way you could use `:dependent` for the relationship with the join model.